# Infinite loop or repetitive run for daemon

Tags: oracle

Which is the better to write a "daemon" based on oracle schedules:

1. The one that is run once and then is in infinite loop and sleeps for 5 seconds if there is nothing to do (to not waste CPU cycles).
2. The one that is started, checked if it is something to do. If not - ends execution and is run after 5 seconds by schedule.

Which one and why do you prefer? Or may be it is some another implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer an infinite loop to a scheduled task. With an infinite loop you can see a broader cross-activation overview - Eg You can count number of failures in a row/similar very easily and add error-recovery.

A scheduled task is effectively stateless unless you manually give it state (File/Db/???)

Comment: Number of failures is counted automatically by scheduler (if a program has really failed). The idle run (the iteration when we did nothing) is not a failure. Also in case of infinite loop solution we have a lot of objects locked (that depends on a schedule program) and to update them we need to stop all the daemons. It is a big minus for such solution.

Comment: Then you've answered your own question. When I said failures, yes a non-0 exit code can be detected but you mentioned remote resources - what happens if remote server is down, do you handle multiple remote resources per run? If the only 3 possible outcomes are success, no work and failure, scheduled sounds like the way to go

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to look at using an a queue to do the processing rather than a schedule job.  The process can block on the queue waiting for new work.

Comment: Yes, I expected such kind of answer ;-) I use AQ when it is worth it and when it is a good place to use, but this case is not. It is a little difficult to explain why. In 2 words: "daemon" works with remote resources.